# Lambda and Math operation

Tags: c#

I need some help with this:

I have a lambda function that looks like this:

```
Func<double, double> f = (x) => (Math.Pow(2 * x, 3) + Math.Pow(x, 2)) + ((5 * x) + 7);
```

It then returns 555 when it was supposed to return 171.

So I found out that the order should be:

```
7 + (5 * x)

(x^2) + (2x^3)
```

And then add those results together, is there a way to change the order in which it's calculated because parentheses don't seem to work here

Comment: but adding is commutativity so it doesn't matter and parentheses  are not required at all  ... but 2x^3 is not (2x)^3 (`Math.Pow(2 * x, 3)`)

Comment: Like @Selvin said, I think you actually want `2 * Math.Pow(x,3)` or even `2 * x * x * x`

Comment: `Func<double, double> f = (x) => new double[] { 2, 1, 5, 7 }.Aggregate((s, a) => s * x + a);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parenthesis do work, if you set them in the correct position.

If you want `f(4)` to return 171 instead of 555 the correct expression is

```
2 * Math.Pow(x,3) + Math.Pow(x,2) + x * 5 + 7
```

The way you wrote it it does `(2*x)^3` instead of `2*(x^3)`

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem you need to extract the constant 2 from Math.Pow()

```
Func<double, double> f = (x) => 2*Math.Pow(x, 3) + Math.Pow(x, 2) + (5 * x) + 7;
```